# Finding annotated annotations

Tags: java, annotations

There is an annotation `@MarkerAnnotation`. It can be added directly to method. or to any other annotation, like

```
@MarkerAnnotation
@Interface CustomAnnotation {...}
```

and this `@CustomAnnotation` can also be added directly to methods. That's the standard way many frameworks let users add their own annotation (e.g. spring).

Now, given a class, I want to find all methods marked directly or indirectly with `@MarkerAnnotation`. For every method I also want to find the associated `@MarkerAnnotation` and/or `@CustomAnnotation`. Is there any tool that I can use or I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2):

Spring has an `AnnotationUtils` class in their core project that does what you want.  The javadoc for `findAnnotation`:

> Find a single Annotation of annotationType on the supplied Method,
>   traversing its super methods (i.e., from superclasses and interfaces)
>   if the annotation is not directly present on the given method itself.
>   Correctly handles bridge Methods generated by the compiler.
>
> Meta-annotations will be searched if the annotation is not directly
>   present on the method.
>
> Annotations on methods are not inherited by default, so we need to
>   handle this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic approach, you should use the annotation processor facility of `javac`, which requires you to write an annotation processor which uses the APIs in packages `javax.annotation.processing`, and `javax.lang.model` and its subpackages. This code will run inside `javac`. (There is an older tool, `apt`, which is separate from `javac`, but `apt` is deprecated in Java 7.)

In particular, when you visit each `Element`, you can call `getAnnotationMirrors` on it. Then,  for each of those annotations, call `getAnnotationType().asElement()` to get the `Element` for the annotation type. You may need to use recursion to find the indirect annotations, if there is more than one level of indirection possible.

Answer (score 0):

for example like this...

```
public class Test{
         @MarkerAnnotation
         public void TestMethod1(){

         }

         @CustomAnnotation
         @MarkerAnnotation
         public void TestMethod2(){

         }

    }
```

you can parse like this..

```
public class AnnotationTest{

         public static void main(String[] args){
              Method[] methods = Test.class.getDeclaredMethods();
              for(Method method: methods){
                   Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
               for(Annotation annotation: annotations){
                   if(annotation instanceof MarkerAnnotation)
                           System.out.println(method.getName() +" annotated with MarkerAnnotation");
                      if(annotation instanceof CustomAnnotation)
                           System.out.println(method.getName() +" annotated with CustomAnnotation");
                   }
              }
         }
    }
```

and if you want check CustomAnnotation have MarkerAnnotation, then do like this..

```
    if(CustomAnnotation.class.isAnnotation()){
        Annotation[] annotations = CustomAnnotation.class.getAnnotations();
        if(annotations[0] instanceof MarkerAnnotation){
            System.out.println("CustomAnnotation have MarkerAnnotation");
        }
    }
```